# Django in multiple servers

Tags: django, django-urls

I am trying to set up a django server, and I would like to have the admin pages in `admin.example.com/app_name`, the api endpoints in `api.example.com/app_name` and the normal pages in `www.example.com/app_name`. I tried to do it via nginx, but internal links are messed up, and I have redirects. Is what I am trying even possible in django?

Answer (score 0):

This is quick and dirty nginx setting that will handle all the requirement I guess

if it doesnt work let me know the error from the /var/log/nginx/error.log and access.log

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:9001; 
}
#main server
server {
    location /admin {
    deny all;
    }
   location /static {
       alias /var/www/static;
    }
 location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include         uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
#your api server
server {
server api.example.com
    location /admin {
    deny all;
    }
       location /static {
       alias /var/www/static;
    }
 location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include         uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
server {
    server_name admin.example.com; 
    location /static {
       alias /var/www/static;
    }
    location /admin {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include         uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
    location / {
    deny all;
    }
}
```